# Is it possible to tell whether your Android app was purchased from the Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I want to know whether my Android application was downloaded from the Playstore or another source.

Is this possible without setting some constants at compile time and using different APK's?

Thanks

Comment: Purchased or just plain downloaded for free?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To determine whether or not the app was *ever* downloaded from the Play Store, you could use [Application Licensing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html). This should pass tests, even if the app was downloaded free. However, if the user has downloaded the app, uninstalled it, then installed it from another source, it might still pass tests here.

I have a dual-sourced app, and I change the version string to end in `.G` for the Play Store app, and a different postfix for the other source. Yes, it requires me to maintain two packages, but at least I don't need to change the package name. Conceivably, I could automate that, as it's only an element in the manifest.

Comment: Thanks, I will check this, I only need it for analytics so it doesn't necessarily need to be super accurate :)